# Find the elements that are not in both objects vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, list, object

I'm trying to loop over two columns in two worksheets, if an element is in both columns i sort it in a datagrid otherwise, if it's only in one (in the worksheet ws1) and it doesn't exist in the other column I also wanna add it to the datagrid saying not found but the problem that I don't know how to find the one that exists in only the first myarray (first column), I will post part of my code maybe it will explain more.

```
Dim ws1 as excel.worksheet
Dim ws2 as excel.worksheet
 ws1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text).Worksheets(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
 ws2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text).Worksheets(ComboBox2.SelectedItem)

Dim findme1 As Excel.Range = ws1.Range("A4:A" & Range1.Rows.Count)
Dim findme2 As Excel.Range = ws2.Range("F5:F" & Range2.Rows.Count)
Dim MyArray As Object(,) = CType(findme1.Value, Object(,))
Dim MyArrayy As Object(,) = CType(findme2.Value, Object(,))


For n = 1 To MyArray.Length
    For m = 1 To MyArrayy.Length
       If MyArray(n, 1) = MyArrayy(m, 1) Then
             Form2.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(MyArray(n, 1), MyArrayy(m, 1), "Found")
       End If

    Next
Next
```

Can you please help me find the one that do not exist in both columns?

Comment: Check if some of the methods of HashSet(Of T) would work for your.

Comment: There should be some options in System.Linq that would do what you want.  You might need to use `Cast(Of T)` to access them; `System.Array` implements `IEnumerable` but I'm not sure it implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
For n = 1 To MyArray.Length
   Dim found as boolean = false
   For m = 1 To MyArrayy.Length
      If MyArray(n, 1) = MyArrayy(m, 1) Then
         Form2.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(MyArray(n, 1), MyArrayy(m, 1), "Found")
         found = true
         exit for
      End If
   Next
   If found = false then
      Form2.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(MyArray(n, 1), "", "Not Found")
   End If 
Next
```